# WMS layer issue at higher zoom level

Tags: gdal, wms, error, mapserver

When zooming out to higher level for a WMS layer, getting this error:

`msDrawMap(): Image handling error. Failed to draw layer named 'PICT-INHEND19-psQwiZ1L4t'. drawGDAL(): Unable to access file. GDALDatasetRasterIO() failed: /tmp/mapfilePassthru-v2-temp-HxmyxI, band 1: IReadBlock failed at X offset 1064, Y offset 1551.`

Checked the mapfile which is fine and also present there. Don't know why this is coming for only certain zoom levels.

Comment: The error comes from GDAL that is used for reading the source data. The image file may be partially corrupted or then there is some problem with the GDAL build. Offsets are counted from the top-left corner of the image, if the GetMap request does not need data from that location then there is no error. Do you administrate that MapServer? You could try to make a copy of the problematic image with gdal_translate and see it it reports the same error.

Comment: how can i test this locally like debug mapserver locally, it's written in C/C++

Comment: and the thing you mentioned about image file being corrupted, image is coming fine from the  gserve request and  this is only happening for higher zoom levels.

Comment: Then the corruption may be in some of the overviews. Some GDAL users have experienced similar issues but where the error happens has been hard to find https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/issues/5489.

Comment: this issue is different i think from this one  The WMS vendor also reported: 
             msDrawMap(): Image handling error. Failed to draw layer named 'PICT-INHEND19-psQwiZ1L4t'.
             drawGDAL(): Unable to access file. GDALDatasetRasterIO() failed: /tmp/mapfilePassthru-v2-temp-aA4Aqf, band 1: IReadBlock failed at X offset 532, Y offset 775

Comment: Does your raster layer use tileindex? Add `debug 5` into your layer and forward error messages into ms_errorfile. Perhaps you will get more accurate info about the failure. Having CPL_DEBUG may help https://mapserver.org/optimization/debugging.html.

Comment: that i tried adding the debug 5 but getting the same error still and the ms_errorfile is empty

Comment: With debug 5 the errorfile will certainly gather new rows if you have configured it right even when there are no errors. But if you run MapServer as fast-cgi then the writing to the log may lag behind. Normal cgi writes into log immediately.